# Resources built as a content

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, resources

I have to change approach to my resources. I have ASP.NET MVC3 Razor project, and my resources were in folder /Resources/Views. They were built as resource so I was using them like that: Namespace.FileName.Key.
Now I want to change it to be built as a content because we need to change them without compiling project.

I found this question [ASP.NET MVC - Non-Embedded Resource FIle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028538/asp-net-mvc-non-embedded-resource-file) . I am calling my resources like he is, but I'm always getting null. This is how I do it:

```
public static string GetResource(string file, string name)
{
    return HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(file, name, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString();
}
```

What is wrong here? I assumed that file is the name of resource file, and name is the name of key in this file. Maybe I am wrong?